# How to read names into a pointer array and output them?

Tags: c++, pointers, file-io, cout

Here is what I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int characterList = 0;
    char* dynamo = new char[1000];
    char* buffer = dynamo;
    ifstream input("wordlist.txt");
    if (input.is_open())
    {
        input >> dynamo[characterList];
        while (input.eof())
        {
            characterList++;
            input >> dynamo[characterList];
            cout << dynamo[characterList];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File not opened" << endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

I'm a beginner so I do apologize if this looks like terrible coding practice. I created a text file with a quote from Bill Cosby that I'm trying to read one word at a time. The quote is "I don't know the key to success, but the key to failure is trying to please everybody." I'm trying to read one word at a time from a text document ignoring punctuation. I know there are a lot of questions similar to this, but they are using code that I have not learned so I'm sorry for having a repeating question. I have not learned `getline` (I used `cin.getline`) and `#include <string>`.

Edit: I forgot to mention, so I'm sorry for not doing so earlier, but I'm studying dynamic memory allocation which is why I'm using the new char[1000].

Comment: I'd recommend learning how to use C++ string abstraction.  You might not have learned it yet, but now's the time.

Comment: @Rie Kumar The code would be simple if you use std::vector<std::string> instead of the array.

Comment: ... and fixed `while (input.eof())`, [which is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @Rie Kumar As for you code then you have to declare a two-dimensional array each element of which would have the size that at least equal to the size of the maximum data in the file.

Comment: What is the problem you're having with this code currently?

Comment: Working strings as buffers and pointers is unecessary and retrograde. This is C++ not C, use the tools it offers.

Comment: Well, my instructor would dock me big time for using the std::string and the code is not outputting any of the text stored on the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use **`std::string`** instead of manually allocating buffers on the heap with `new[]` and trying to read text manually from the file into those buffers (and don't forget to free the buffer with proper `delete[]` calls!).

C++ input stream classes like **`std::ifstream`** can simply read text into `std::string` instances thanks to a proper overload of `operator<<`.
The syntax is as simple as:

```
    string word;
    while (inFile >> word)
    {
        cout << word << endl;
    }
```

Here's a complete compilable sample code for you to experiment and learn:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        string word;
        while (inFile >> word)
        {
            cout << word << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Can't open file." << endl;
    }    
}
```

This is the output I got on a test text file having the content specified in your question:

> ```
> I
> don't
> know
> the
> key
> to
> success,
> but
> the
> key
> to
> failure
> is
> trying
> to
> please
> everybody.
> ```

---

**NOTE**

Of course, once you have your words read into a `std::string` instance, you can store them in a container like `std::vector<std::string>`, using its `push_back()` method.

Comment: I can't use #include<string> & std::string. I really wish I could because from most of the answers so far it seems the easiest. Unfortunately, my instructor would dock me quite a bit of points for using something we haven't learned yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::string array[6];
  std::ifstream infile("Team.txt");
  std::string line;
  int i = 0;
  while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
    array[i++] = line;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/2411320) answer.

Here, we assume we have to read 6 lines from the file "Team.txt". We use [std:::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and we put inside a `while` so that we read all the file.

At every iteration, `line` holds the current line of the file read. Inside the body we store it in `array[i]`.

Comment: I can't use #include<string> & std::string. I really wish I could because from most of the answers so far it seems the easiest. Unfortunately, my instructor would dock me quite a bit of points for using something we haven't learned yet.